# Why can't java find a file?

Tags: java, file

Being trying to get this to work for an hour now and I just can't seem to figure it out. Looked a few places online and I can't spot what I'm doing wrong.

Apparently theres an issue with the `Scanner` being unable to find the file.

Here is my code:

```
package week07;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FrequencyGenerator implements WordGenerator {
    private Random random;

    public FrequencyGenerator(Random r) {
        File file = new File("letter-frequencies.txt");

        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
        double[] frequencyArray = new double[22];

        for (double d : frequencyArray) {
            d = Double.valueOf(fileScan.nextLine());
            System.out.println(d);
        }
        fileScan.close();
    }

    public String nextWord(int n) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
File: C:\Users\USER8\Desktop\cosc241\07\week07... [line: 17]
Error: Unhandled exception type java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: The file is not in the directory?

Comment: Read the tutorial about exceptions. Also, you should really understand the difference between compiling code and executing it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that the file cannot be found, it is that your code has a compile error.

Another problem is that you seem to want to fill your arrays with numbers, except that it won't happen.

Also, since this is 2015, you want to use java.nio.file instead of File:

```
private static final Charset UTF8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
private static final int LEN = 22;

// ...

public FrequencyGenerator(final Random r)
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get("letter-frequencies.txt");

    try (
        final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, UTF8);
    ) {
        final double[] array = new double[LEN];

        for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
            array[i] = Double.valueOf(reader.readLine());
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

There are also other problems (such as, for example, you don't specify the charset when opening the file; the `r` constructor parameter is unused; your array is never used; this will bug if the file has less than 22 lines; etc etc), but then the intent of the code is not clearly stated so it's hard to fix all problems.

Finally, if you use Java 8 the code can be simplified further.

Answer (score 1):

The file should be present in same directory where your class file exists. Or else enter the relative or absolute path of the file as a parameter while the creation of the File object.

Comment: My class file is definitely in the same directory as the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
File file = new File("\\letter-frequencies.txt");
```

Comment: That won't compile; `"\l"` is not a legal escape sequence in a Java string literal

Comment: What about this one?

Comment: That's better, but then there is no need for the leading separator; by default paths are resolved against the working directory of the process. And then this is 2015 so you should drop File anyway :p

Comment: plus one! So true... fge